# How can you create a vertical navbar with drop down menus?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, vertical-alignment, navbar

I have a vertical navbar. Now, this navbar is supposed to have drop down menus. The only problem for me is, I am unable to make it so that the drop down menus are to the side of the menu. I have the `HTML and CSS` code on jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/maxkoenig/ZYUeX/
Here it is if you don't want to go on the website:
HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
          <ul class="navbar">
             <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="/boattypes/featureboats.php">Boat Types</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/boattypes/sprint/sprint.php">Sprint</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/boattypes/fitnesstouring/fitnesstouring.php">Fitness-touring</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/boattypes/marathon/marathon.php">High Performance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/boattypes/surfski/surfskis.php">Surf Skis</a></li>
                </ul>         
             </li>
             <li><a href="/rent/services.php">Inventory</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/rent/memb.php">Membership</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/rent/rboat.php" >Rentals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/rent/rb.php">Banquet</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/rent/faq.php">FAQ</a></li>

                </ul>         
             </li>
             <li><a href="/ages/ages.php">Ages</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="/ages/adult.php">Adults</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/ages/children.php">Children</a></li>

                </ul>         
             </li>
             <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a>
                 <li><a href="contact_us.php">Contact Us</a>
                </ul>
       </div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap {
    width: 150px; 
    height: 50px; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0; /* Ensures there is no space between sides of the screen and the menu */
    z-index: 1; /* Makes sure that your menu remains on top of other page elements */
    position: fixed;
    background-color: RoyalBlue;

    }
.navbar {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed; /* Ensures that the menu doesn’t affect other elements */
    border-right: 1px solid #54879d; 
    z-index: 12;
    }
.navbar li  {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            height: auto;
            width: 150px;  /* Each menu item is 150px wide */
            /*float: left;   This lines up the menu items horizontally */
            object-position: top;
            text-align: center;  /* All text is placed in the center of the box */
            list-style: none;  /* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */
            font: normal bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;  
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: RoyalBlue;
                        }
.navbar a   {                           
        padding: 18px 0;  /* Adds a padding on the top and bottom so the text appears centered vertically */
        border-left: 1px solid #0026ff; /* Creates a border in a slightly lighter shade of blue than the background.  Combined with the right border, this creates a nice effect. */
        border-right: 1px solid #0026ff; /* Creates a border in a slightly darker shade of blue than the background.  Combined with the left border, this creates a nice effect. */
        text-decoration: none;  /* Removes the default hyperlink styling. */
        color: #000; /* Text color is black */
        display: block;
        }

.navbar li:hover, a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(4, 6, 0, 0.00);
}

.navbar li ul   {
        display: none;  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
        height: auto;                                   
        margin: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
        padding: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */         
        }               

.navbar li:hover ul     {
                        display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
                        z-index: 12;
                        padding-left: 1px;

                        }

.navbar li ul li {
    background-color: #2ba6ff;
}

.navbar li ul li a  {
        border-left: 1px solid #0026ff;
        border-right: 1px solid #0026ff;
        border-top: 1px solid #0026ff;
        z-index: 1001;
        }

.navbar li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #0094ff;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
.navbar li ul
{
    display: none; /* Hides the drop-down menu */   
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    float:left;
    height: 0;
}
```

Here's the jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/ZYUeX/3/