# Html Horizontal drop downs with with a vertical navbar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown, navigationbar

In Html how would I be able to create a vertical nav bar with drop downs to the side but instead of the dropdowns going down I want them to go horizontally? 
Can anyone help thank you for your time.!

For example something like this where the drop down extends to the right, but not just with one option
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/imS0i.jpg]

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682928/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-navbar-with-drop-down-menus). It seems to address your issue exactly.

Comment: Sorry, Dan, i seem to have not asked the right question but hopefully, the picture will help understand how I want the vertical navbar with dropdowns extending to the right, instead of the dropdowns going right and down. How I want them to go horizontally not down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see. I don't know if this helps, but I updated the fiddle from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682928/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-navbar-with-drop-down-menus)

Here is that same fiddle with small changes: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dankreiger/ZYUeX/700/)

Changing the css on line 74 from `display: block` to `display: flex` gives the effect that I think you want.

Comment: Thank you,  Dan, for this really appreciate you helping me out I wish I could give you something in return thank you so much really helped me out here.